# Preventing Apache Infinite Looping POST Requests

Tags: php, android, apache

I am building a chat application in Android using XAMPP and websockets. After sending a group message, that message appears in the database and in all the other group members screens as it should. However, viewing in the Apache access.log, there is the one GET/ request and then hundreds of POST/ actions, whereby looking at the users mobile screens there is then that same message displayed hundreds of times.

Is there a remedy for this? A setting that can be changed in Apache so as to prevent the looping?

Sample from Apache access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014:12:47:48 -0400] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4655 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
  - - [02/Aug/2014:12:47:57 -0400] "POST /AndroidChatterDatabase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; SGH-T989 Build/IML74K)"
  - - [02/Aug/2014:12:47:57 -0400] "POST /AndroidChatterDatabase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; SGH-T989 Build/IML74K)"
  - - [02/Aug/2014:12:47:57 -0400] "POST /AndroidChatterDatabase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; SGH-T989 Build/IML74K)"
  - - [02/Aug/2014:12:47:57 -0400] "POST /AndroidChatterDatabase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; SGH-T989 Build/IML74K)"
  - - [02/Aug/2014:12:48:12 -0400] "POST /AndroidChatterDatabase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; SGH-T989 Build/IML74K)"
  - - [02/Aug/2014:12:48:12 -0400] "POST /AndroidChatterDatabase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; SGH-T989 Build/IML74K)"
  - - [02/Aug/2014:12:48:12 -0400] "POST /AndroidChatterDatabase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; SGH-T989 Build/IML74K)"
  - - [02/Aug/2014:12:48:12 -0400] "POST /AndroidChatterDatabase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; SGH-T989 Build/IML74K)"
  - - [02/Aug/2014:12:48:27 -0400] "POST /AndroidChatterDatabase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; SGH-T989 Build/IML74K)"
  - - [02/Aug/2014:12:48:27 -0400] "POST /AndroidChatterDatabase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; SGH-T989 Build/IML74K)"
```

Comment: apache is not the problem. the requests are being made by the clients, so there is something wrong there.

Comment: @JohnKiller Thank you. Are you familiar with where the many requests could be originated from. I am using Websockets and XAMPP for the chat, the one-to-one is not looping but group chat is. May we setup a chat? I can share the code with you